# awk to append data based on match and add header

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below I am storing the value of `$1` in `file1` in`a` then looking in `$1` of `file2` for a match. If they do then the value in `$2` of `file2` is appended to `file1`.
I am also trying to add a header (Number) to `$4`, but I am not sure how.

**file1**  `comma separated`

```
[...],,
...,
[...],,
...,
[Data],,
ID,_A,_B
aaa00-00,...,0
aaa00-11,...,1
aaa00-22,...,2
```

**file2**  `space delimitied`

```
aaa00-00 0.1257
aaa00-11 0.1263
aaa00-22 0.1239
```

**desired**  `comma separated`

```
[...],,
...,
[...],,
...,
[Data],,
ID,_A,_B,Number
aaa00-00,...,0,0.1257
aaa00-11,...,1,0.1263
aaa00-22,...,2,0.1239
```

**awk**

```
awk '
BEGIN   { FS=OFS="," }       # define FS an OFS as comma
/^Data/    { next }          # only operate in the Data section or move on
FNR==NR { a[$1]=$1; next }   # condition which will be TRUE when file2 is being read and creating array a with index of $1 and value of $1
    { $4= ($2 in a) }        # check if 1st field matches and printing value in $4 if it does
1
' file1 file2
```

Comment: is each record in `file1` guaranteed to have a match in`file2`? and if not, then what's to be printed in the 4th column ... a blank?

Comment: yes there will always be a record from `file1` that matches in `file2`, sorry forgot to put that. Thank you :).

Comment: Are the matching strings between the 2 files guaranteed to be in the same order in each file?

Comment: Yes, the order will be the same as well. Thank you  ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions/understandings:

- each `Data` line from `file1` will have a matching line from `file2`
- while not shown in the sample input, assume there may be other blocks after the `[Data]` block that are to be left as is

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN        { FS=OFS="," }
FNR==NR      { split($0,a,/[[:space:]]+/)                   # resplit 1st file contents on white space
               map[a[1]]=a[2]
               next
             }
/^\[/        { process_data=0 }                             # disable "Data" processing if line starts with "["
process_data { $(NF+1)=($1 == "ID" ? "Number" : map[$1]) }  # define (NF+1) field
/^\[Data\]/  { process_data=1 }                             # enable "Data" processing
1                                                           # print current line
' file2 file1
```

This generates:

```
[...],,
...,
[...],,
...,
[Data],,
ID,_A,_B,Number
aaa00-00,...,0,0.1257
aaa00-11,...,1,0.1263
aaa00-22,...,2,0.1239
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on it that should work in any POSIX compliant [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) version.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {
    m[$1]=$2; next              # make a map of the keys and values in file2
}
{
    if(/^\[Data\]/ ) Data=1;    # set Data to 1 if the Data section starts 
    else if(/^\[.*\]/ ) Data=0; # set Data to 0 if the Data section ends
    else if(Data) {             # if we're in the data section
        FS=",";                 # separate fields on comma
        if(/^ID,/) $0 = $0 FS "Number"; # add heading
        else $0 = $0 FS m[$1]   # add value from the mapped key/value pair (if any)
    }
}1' file2 file1                 # the 1 makes it print the line
```

... or using the compact form of the same thing:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { m[$1]=$2; next }
/^\[.*\]/    { Data=0 }
Data         { FS=","; $0 = $0 FS (/^ID,/ ? "Number" : m[$1]) }
/^\[Data\]/  { Data=1 }
1' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
NR==FNR {
    map[$1] = $2
    next
}
FS == ","  { $(NF+1) = ( n++ ? map[$1] : "Number" ) }
/^\[Data]/ { FS = "," }
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
[...],,
...,
[...],,
...,
[Data],,
ID,_A,_B,Number
aaa00-00,...,0,0.1257
aaa00-11,...,1,0.1263
aaa00-22,...,2,0.1239
```

Comment: Heads up: This will map values matching in other sections than `[Data]` too.

Comment: @TedLyngmo only if they came later in the file but I don't see anything in the question suggesting that issue exists for the OP. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: No, you are correct. I just thought it was worth a heads up in case you'd like to prevent that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'll tweak it if the OP says it's a problem (after getting them to update the example in their question to include that case).

Comment: There is nothing under the `Data` section. Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[ ,]' -v OFS=',' -v mat='[Data]' -v col='Number' '
    NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next}
    $1==mat {print; getline h; print h,col; next}  
    ($1 in a) {$(NF+1)=a[$1]}1
' file2 file1
```

---

```
[...],,
...,
[...],,
...,
[Data],,
ID,_A,_B,Number
aaa00-00,...,0,0.1257
aaa00-11,...,1,0.1263
aaa00-22,...,2,0.1239
```